# Need to specify class name in environment or system property error

Tags: maven, glassfish, glassfish-4, netbeans-8

I'm testing Remote EJB from a standlone client to a call a jar file deployed in a glassfish server 4, but it show me the following message:

```
Grave: null
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at mx.com.gm.sga.cliente.ClientePersonaService.main(ClientePersonaService.java:39)
```

My code is :

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println("------------Calling EJB from a client --------------- ");
    try {
        InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext( );

        PersonaServiceRemote personaService = (PersonaServiceRemote) jndi.lookup( "java:global/sga-jee/PersonaServiceImpl!mx.com.gm.sga.servicio.PersonaServiceRemote" );
        List< Persona > personas = personaService.listarPersonas();
        for (Persona persona : personas) {
            System.out.println( persona );
        }
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientePersonaService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.out.println("------------End calling EJB --------------- ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JNDI allows different providers. For the initial context the name of the actual implementation is specified with the system property `java.naming.factory.initial`. In case of GlassFish according to the [FAQ](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html) you don't need this. But I think it requires that you add the correct glassfish client library in order to make it work with the default context: `$GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib/gf-client.jar`. Check out the FAQ, it lists a few different cases (standalone, app client, second app server, ...).

Answer (score 0):

the error was for the:
**JDTA connection in the Persistence Unit.**
***I configure the Persistence Unit as JDTA and I created the pool connection in GlassFish and whole work fine.***
;)